# Start android function 2 or 3 time

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery, webview

this is my jquery code :

```
function fill_comment(){
document.getElementById('dynamicContent').innerHTML = "";
var text = ReadDB();
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
for (i = 0; i < obj.Message.length; i++) {
document.getElementById('dynamicContent').innerHTML += '<div class=\"comment-list clearfix\" id=\"'+obj.Message[i].ID+'\"><ol><li class=\"comment\" id=\"'+obj.Message[i].ID+'\"><div class=\"comment-top\"><span></span></div><div class=\"comment-body\"><div class=\"comment-text\"><div class=\"comment-author clearfix\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"link-author\">'+obj.Message[i].App+'</a><span class=\"comment-date\">'+obj.Message[i].Date+'</span><a href=\"#addcomments\" class=\"link-reply2 anchor\"></a><a href=\"#addcomments\" class=\"link-reply1 anchor\"></a><a href=\"#addcomments\" class=\"link-reply anchor\"></a>  |  <input name=\"\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"\"></div><div class=\"comment-entry\">'+obj.Message[i].Content+'</div></div></div></li></ol><div>';}
$( ".comment" ).draggable({axis: "x"},{
        drag: function( event, ui ) {
            var direction = (ui.originalPosition.left > ui.position.left) ? 'left' : 'right';
            if(direction == "left")
            {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $(this).fadeOut(700).delay(500);
                AndroidFunction.DelCheck(id);
            }
            else
            {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $(this).fadeOut(700);
                AndroidFunction.SaveDialog(id);
            }
        }
});}
```

This is my java code :

```
public void DelCheck(final String idCheck)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidHTMLActivity.this);
        myDialog.setTitle("حذف");
        myDialog.setMessage("برای حذف مطمئن هستید؟");
        myDialog.setPositiveButton("بلی", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                final SQLiteDatabase mydatabase1 = openOrCreateDatabase("CopyCollection", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                mydatabase1.execSQL("DELETE FROM Details WHERE ID = "+idCheck+";");
                mydatabase1.close();
            }
        });
        myDialog.setNegativeButton("خیر", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:fade_back("+idCheck+")");
            }
        });
        myDialog.show();
    }
    public void SaveDialog(final String SaveID)
    {
        final SQLiteDatabase mydatabase1 = openOrCreateDatabase("CopyCollection", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor c = mydatabase1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Details WHERE ID="+SaveID+";", null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                appName = c.getString(1);
                txtClip = c.getString(2);
                text_Date = c.getString(3);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
```

I have a jquery function that whene I drag div to left it start android function

```
AndroidFunction.DelCheck(id);
```

but whene i drag to left function start 2 or 3 time and i saw dialog box 2 or 3 time in android webview

Comment: what this `for (i = 0; i < obj.Message.length; i++) {` do?

Comment: You have to think about when your `drag` function will fire.  I believe if will fire continuously as you drag. Maybe try `stop` or `start` functions instead.  Whichever makes more sense for your application.

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira : when I call this function get all record from sqlite and create json object to insert records in HTML

Comment: @James : how can I know whene function stop to start android function?